# How to Install Downloaded Programs?

Tags: installation

I am Trying to Install Qucs-0.0.16 please Help me how to install this Simulation Software which i was downloaded in the ta.gz format , I have tried some of the steps given but its not working please Help Me...!

Comment: see his other topic @EricCarvalho >:D http://askubuntu.com/questions/280293/how-to-overcome-this-error

Comment: Rajath, please don't post the same question twice.