# Installing Qucs manually displays Qt header errors

Tags: installation

```
rajath@Rajathkumar:~$ cd Downloads
rajath@Rajathkumar:~/Downloads$ cd qucs-0.0.16
rajath@Rajathkumar:~/Downloads/qucs-0.0.16$ ./configure
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for ar... ar
checking for lrelease-qt3... no
checking for lrelease... /usr/bin/lrelease
checking for lupdate-qt3... no
checking for lupdate... /usr/bin/lupdate
checking for moc-qt3... no
checking for moc... /usr/bin/moc
checking for uic-qt3... no
checking for uic... /usr/bin/uic
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for X... libraries , headers 
checking for gethostbyname... yes
checking for connect... yes
checking for remove... yes
checking for shmat... yes
checking for IceConnectionNumber in -lICE... no
checking for Qt headers... configure: error: not found
```

Comment: Compiling QUCS is not really straightforward. If you do not want to develop it, I recommend the PPA: `ppa:fransschreuder1/qucs`. It works ok. If you *do* want to develop, better to subscribe to the mailing list and ask there. You have building instruction at https://github.com/Qucs/qucs/wiki/Build-Linux

Answer (score 2):

`apt-cache search libqt | grep headers` returns

```
libqt3-compat-headers - Qt 1.x and 2.x compatibility includes
libqt3-headers - Qt3 header files
libqtgstreamer-dev - Development headers for QtGStreamer
```

That is a basic example of how to search for dependencies you don't have. Also see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=124483 post #8 for a more thorough explanation.

It looks like you're going to want to grab the second one and install it. If you don't know how: `sudo apt-get install libqt3-headers` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

At least for me it worked out to

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libqt4-dev libqt4-qt3support automake libtool gperf flex bison git cmake
```

from https://github.com/Qucs/qucs/wiki/Build-Linux

and go on with

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: This one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `componentdialog.moc.cpp` or `many ~~~.moc.cpp` files seem to be get created automatic by `/use/bin/moc-qt4` when you do successfully `./configure` and `make`.

You do not see them in your source files. So you need to have already some qt4 binary package installed. I am on puppy-linux so had `qt_all-4.7.3.sfs` installed but with it I could not get not far compiling SUCS so uninstalled them. Yet I had `/usr/bin/moc-qt4` somehow from previous qt installation.

You have the source file of QUCS unpacked "somewhere" with a command:

```
tar -xvzf qucs-0.0.18.131128.tar.gz
```

(0.0.18.131128) was the version number of my package. Let call the "somewhere" as SRC-DIR.

To compile **Qucs** you need to install:

- `libqt3-compat-headers_3.deb`
- `libqt3-headers_3.deb`
- `libqt4-dev_4.deb`

Go to [filewatcher.com](http://www.filewatcher.com/) and enter these file name in the search box and press search button one by one to find them to download and install them.

When you have installed them:

- `libqt4-dev_4.deb` would be in `/usr/include/qt4`.
- `libqt3-compat-headers_3.deb` and `libqt3-headers_3.deb` would be in `/usr/include/qt3`.

You need to do to make a symlink to the `/usr/include/qt4` with the name "Qt" as `/usr/include/~Q`t as **Qucs** `configure` file seem to be looking for the directory `/usr/include/Qt` instead of `/usr/include/qt4` or `qy3` with the next command:

```
ln -s /usr/include/qt4 /usr/include/Qt (Enter) to make the sim-link /usr/include/~Qt.
```

We are almost there to do `./configure` but there seems to be a bit of confusion in the `/usr/include/qt4` (~QT) directory.
Many of the header files are not in the right place. Because it would require so many of them you might well copy all `.h` files in `/usr/include/qt4/Qt/*.h` into as `/usr/include/qt4/*.h` with this command: 
    cp /usr/include/qt4/Qt/*.h /usr/include/qt4

And make a link to `/usr/include/qt4/QtGui` in `/usr/include` with the following command:

```
ln -s /usr/include/qt4/QtGui /usr/include/QtGui
```

You also need to copy files listed below to `/usr/include/qt4` directory from `/usr/include/qt4/Qt3Support` and `/usr/include/qt4/QtCore` directories.

- Q3Dict (from `/Qt3Support`), `cp /usr/include/qt4/Qt3Support/Q3Dict /usr/include/qt4`
- Q3GridLayout (from `/Qt3Support`),   `cp /usr/include/qt4/Qt3Support/Q3GridLayout  /usr/include/qt4`
- Q3PtrList (from `/Qt3Support`),  `cp /usr/include/qt4/Qt3Support/Q3PtrList  /usr/include/qt4`
- Q3ScrollView (from `/Qt3Support`),   `cp /usr/include/qt4/Qt3Support/Q3ScrollView  /usr/include/qt4`
- Q3TextSream (from `/Qt3Support`),   `cp /usr/include/qt4/Qt3Support/Q3TextStream  /usr/include/qt4`
- Q3VBoxLayout (from `/Qt3Support`),   `cp /usr/include/qt4/Qt3Support/Q3VBoxLayout  /usr/include/qt4`
- QProcess (from `/QtCore`),   `cp /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/QProcess /usr/include/qt4`
- QSettings    (from `/QtCore`),   `cp /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/QSettings /usr/include/qt4`
- These files are links to many of `.h` files in `/usr/include/qt4` (~Qt). If you use mc you can do these very easily?

You also need to copy `/usr/include/qt3/private` directory with it's contents to `/usr/include/qt4` as `/usr/include/qt4/private`.

with the commands:

```
mkdir /usr/include/qt4/private
cp /usr/include/qt3/private/* /usr/include/qt4/private
```

Now, you can do at the SRC-DIR `./configure`. It will, I hope, successfully complete lengthy configuration.

If you do now `make` this will get you almost all the way compiling **Qucs** but it could stop at:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtCore
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtGui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtXml
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt3Support
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQtSvg
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [qucs] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/SRC/qucs-0.0.18.131128/qucs'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/SRC/qucs-0.0.18.131128/qucs'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/SRC/qucs-0.0.18.131128'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

If you did not have installed any `libqt4` packages. This is happen to me because I have not installed `libqt4` package. I would  find out package to install and if succeed in compiling Sucs I would post what I did.

Comment: Will +1 if you format your post so that it is readable... click edit and then click on the upper right orange question mark to see the help.